# Deleting event methods

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Accidentally added some event methods in C# from the form builder. If you delete them from the .cs file it throws an error. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: Just delete the line that throws the error.

Comment: @DominicKexel: if he knew it was in the designer and knew how to open it and remove the line, he wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @null probably just counter-upvotes.

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the downvote button, it says "this question shows no research effort or is not useful". The question certainly shows zero research effort. It is also almost 100% a dupe and can be resolved with a simple google search.

Comment: there is no _any_ reason to downvote this quesion. To be able to resolve this OP has to go to the design CS file, so legitimate question "should I touch it" ? "are there better ways to do that" ? *Stop downvoting only because it seems easy _to you_*.

Comment: @Abbas Or he just didn't bother to spend *any* time attempting to solve his own problem or to search for a solution, despite the fact that it's entirely within his capabilities to solve.

Comment: @Tigran But *he didn't ask that legitimate question*.  He asked an entirely different question that demonstrated that he spent no time whatsoever attempting to diagnose the problem, or try and solve it.

Comment: @Servy: still not agree with this behaviour. give people a chance to think over, to validate comments and answers. SO became too choosey and non tollerant. programming is fun, so asking questions should be too.

Comment: I remember when I was a new dev, I always started a new project just because I didn't know how to correct this issue and it was not easy to find. Does SO have an answer for this question so far?

Comment: @Tigran So you're saying that you want to encourage people to post low quality questions, to not do research, to not try to solve their own problems, and to treat SO as a place to get others to just do their work for them, without regard for quality, because that's more entertaining?  Sorry, but I (as well as the site's founders) want SO to be a place for quality questions and quality answers.  It's first priority is not entertainment.

Comment: @Kuzgun At a bare minimum level even a new programmer should be able to look at what the error message is, find the file and line number that indicates its position, and find the relevant code.  Posting a question about a problem *without even so much as indicating what the error message is* is a *very* poor quality question.

Comment: @Servy: for sure not. But "If you delete them from the .cs file it throws an error" phrase manifests fact that OP tried to resolve a problem and fails. He found an error in some obscure for him design file and didn't know what to do.

Comment: @Tigran How did he try to resolve the problem?  He deleted a method, after deleting it an error is thrown.  He didn't even *say what the error message is* in the question.  Regardless of whether or not it's obscure to him, it's absolutely something that belongs in the question.  Beyond that it's something that he can easily search on to find relevant material to explain it in different wording.  The second he came across anything even remotely wrong he went immediately to "get someone else to solve it for me" rather than, "try to figure out what's going on".  We don't want to encourage that.

Comment: It's safe to say that the OP could/should have found it but didn't and asked a rather poor question. This is indeed not to be encouraged but several answers have been given. So for now, let's stop this discussion.

Comment: @Servy I understand you, everyone should do research of course, even it takes hours. But those errors can seem like a foreign language sometimes and this doesn't look like a question just written for fun. And I believe there is no tutorial on net about how to fix the project you messed up.

Comment: @Kuzgun First off, looking at the question, the error message very likely *is* in a foreign language for the OP.  But that doesn't mean he has no possible recourse for solving his problem besides giving up and getting someone else to do it for him.  He has plenty of options available to him, the simplest of which I've already described in comments here.  Those options are entirely possible even if you don't understand a word of the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to subscribing to an event.

- You have the event method itself, which you tried deleting.
- You have subscriptions to the event method. You can have any number of controls subscribing to a single event method.

If you just delete the event method, then you still have controls subscribed to that event. But it no longer exists, so you get an error.

---

You can delete the subscription to the event from the designer by right-clicking the event in the properties window and clicking "Reset":

[image]

Or you could open the `Designer.cs` file and delete event subscription from there. For example:

```
this.richTextBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.richTextBox1_KeyDown);
```

Answer (score 3):

As well as deleting them from the code file, you will need to find the control that is referencing those event methods and remove the reference to the method.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to `Form.Designer.cs` and remove the red line which is subscription of the event handler.If you see an error screen like this:

[image]

Just click the link under the `Instances of this error`, and remove that line and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the button or element that reference the Event and remove it from there, Desingn - > Right click on element -> Properties - > Events - > Remove from there what you dont need, or do it in the code, you can search in it for the name of the method you deleted.

And the next time just use Ctrl + Z.